# Ist „von wegen“ unhöflich?

Tags: slang, interjection

Ist folgender Ausdruck irgendwie grob, unhöflich oder vulgär?

> Von wegen!

Ich vermute, da ist etwas dran. Diese Vermutung basiert drauf, dass dessen Übersetzungen gewissermaßen vulgär klingen.

Wenn *von wegen!* unhöflich ist, würde ich gerne wissen, was dahinter steckt.

Comment: "Von wegen!" simply means "That's not true". It's colloquial but there's definitely nothing rude or vulgar about it.

Comment: Nur, wenn dein darauffolgendes Argument falsch ist, contrare zu dem Inhalt, den du eigentlich wiederlegen möchtest. | Only if you are wrong with your follow up statement (:

Comment: Interesting! We now have 2/2 answers saying almost the opposite each. May there be a north - south difference in usage and meaning?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<sup>Diese Antwort schlägt in die gleiche Kerbe wie [Ingmars](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/11696/2594), würde aber den Rahmen eines Kommentars sprengen.</sup>

Ich beziehe mich nur auf die Verwendung von *von wegen* als allein stehenden Ausdruck:

*Von wegen* drückt **als Reaktion auf eine Aussage** aus, dass diese völlig falsch ist. Weitestgehend äquivalente Phrasen wären:

> Das ist völlig falsch!
>   Ganz und gar nicht!
>   Im Gegenteil!
>   Das stimmt auf gar keinen Fall!

Wie *von wegen* lassen all diese Aussagen weder Spielraum für eine Alternative noch besagen sie, dass es sich nur um die Meinung des Sprechers handelt. Da in den allermeisten Fällen davon auszugehen ist, dass das Gegenüber (oder zumindest irgendjemand) hinter einer Aussage steht, wird ein derartiger alternativloser Widerspruch in diesen Fällen als unhöflich empfunden, da ihm ein gewisser Respekt vor der Aussage und damit dem Gegenüber fehlt¹ – dies gilt aber für alle der obigen Aussagen und liegt nicht an dem Ausdruck selbst, sondern daran, was er aussagt.

Dies wird in den seltenen Fällen deutlich, in denen sich *von wegen* auf eine Aussage bezieht, bei der nicht davon auszugehen ist, dass irgendwer hinter ihr steht. Ein Beispiel ist eine Aussage, bei der allen Beteiligten klar ist, dass sie spekulativ ist, zum Beispiel:

> A: [berichtet über eine amüsante Situation]
>   B: Und dann – lass mich raten – hatte sie ihr Portemonnaie vergessen.
>   A: Von wegen! Sie zückte einen 500-€-Schein!

Ähnliches gilt für den Fall, dass *von wegen* **Reaktion auf eine Frage oder Forderung** ist: Wenn anzunehmen ist, dass der Fragende eine positive Antwort erwartet oder die Forderung ernst gemeint ist, ist *von wegen* aus analogen Gründen unhöflich. Ist die Antwort auf die Frage jedoch z. B. völlig offen (siehe [Takkats Beispiele](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/11700/2594)), ist dies nicht der Fall.

In jedem Fall ist *von wegen* umgangssprachlich, aber nicht vulgär.

Fürs Protokoll: Ich bin in Norddeutschland aufgewachsen.

---

¹ In der Regel wird deshalb zu Phrasen gegriffen, die besagten Spielraum lassen, wie:

> Dem muss ich widersprechen.
>   Das ist meiner Meinung nach völlig falsch.
>   Wenn ich mich nicht irre, ist eher das Gegenteil der Fall.
>   Das ist sehr wahrscheinlich falsch.

Answer (score 7):

Der Ausdruck, "Von wegen!", ist grundsätzlich weder grob, unhöflich, noch vulgär. Er ist doch umgangssprachlich. Die Empfindung dieses Ausdrucks hängt von dem Kontext der Rede ab. Wegen Sarkasmus oder Ton könnte er grob oder unhöfflich sein.

Manche englische Übersetzungen sind vulgär aber manche sind nicht.  Diese Übersetzungen sind idiomatisch, deshalb sind sie grundsätzlich nicht vulgär auf Deutsch.

Quellenangabe: http://www.dict.cc/?s=Von+wegen%21

Answer (score 7):

Nein, es ist nicht vulgär oder stark unhöflich, aber es ist natürlich eine ziemlich starke, emotionale Äußerung. Es ist auch möglich, dass man den Sprecher damit, bewusst oder unbewusst, einer Lüge beschuldigt.

Abgesehen davon besteht aber mE an sich kein Unterschied zum Englischen "Never!" oder "Certainly not!" oä. Von welchen Übersetzungsmöglichkeiten redest Du denn?

Comment: OK, I can think of one (My ass!) that would be considered vulgar, but this is not true for the German expression.

Answer (score 5):

Offenbar haben wir bei den bislang hier gegebenen Antworten gänzlich unterschiedliche Auffassungen, was die Verwendung und Bedeutung von *"von wegen"* anlangt.

Hier im Süden Deutschlands wird *"von wegen"* sehr häufig zur Bestärkung einer Verneinung gehört. Diese ist meist nicht mit einer unhöflichen oder garstigen Antwort verknüpft. Häufig wird noch ein *"Ach"*, *"Ach was"*, oder (schwäbisch) *"Awa"* vorangestellt.

Beispiele:

> War dein Urlaub schön? – Ach, von wegen! Den ganzen Tag hat es geregnet.
>   Habe ich dir zu wenig Geld gegeben? – Ach was, von wegen, du bekommst sogar noch etwas zurück!

Comment: Das ist natürlich eine mögliche Verwendungsform, aber auch hier -- das sind wir uns ja wohl einig -- ist es nicht grob oder unhöflich.

Müsste aber Dein letztes Beispiel nicht lauten "Habe ich dir *zuwenig* Geld gegeben?"

Answer (score 0):

In common conversations, `von wegen` is only used in situations where you hold the other person in low esteem. As a native Northern German speaker, I can say it is only used when you are implying something like `what the fuck makes you think so?`

It is also unwelcome by your conversational partner and has some indication that you don't like to continue the conversation. A nice, polite way to say this (often used by politicians, might be similar to `not at all`) is `im Gegenteil`.

Comment: As a native speaker of (Austrian) German, I disagree with that assessment. To me it neither signifies a desire to end the conversation nor do I consider it "unwelcome" or, as you seem to imply, particularly impolite.

Comment: Könnte auch regional unterschiedlich verstanden werden. Hinzuzufügen wäre noch als höflich erscheinende Alternative das Wort 'keineswegs'. Dies hat in Norddeutschland nicht diese abweisende Konnotation wie 'von wegen'.

Answer (score -5):

*Von wegen!* is impulsive. Impulsive = vulgar – and without any thought or restraint. So yes, it is *unhöflich*. *Höflich* means considerate or polite. Abrupt exclamations like *von wegen* are neither considerate nor polite they are abrupt.

I'm from Thuringia. Born in Erfurt.

My rationale is:
Höflichkeit kommt von Hof --> Gutes Benehmen bei Hofe
Politeness --> Politician
Courteous --> Court --> Hof --> Höflich

Unless you know the other person and are joking. Saying "Von wegen!" is not really the fine English way. It's for me similar to somebody saying *fuck off* in Ireland informally when somebody else is having a laugh.

So you can use it in banter but I'd not use it without intent of being humorous in a serious fashion towards a stranger or official.

The tone after all always is making the music.

A short hand for *von wegen* for me is *pffft*. Or *duh!* in English.

Comment: I disagree. Impulsive: possibly, colloquial: certainly, but by no means "vulgar". Please go and look up the word in a dictionary if you really believe that impulsive and vulgar mean the same thing. I suppose it could be considered impolite, depending on tone, loudness and other circumstances. That's not the same as rude, though, and it certainly is not vulgar.